# How to use Soundcloud API (authentication) with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soundcloud

I already can use the public Soundcloud API, but I am struggling with that callback.html to get that login dialog.

At Soundcloud my App has the following callback redirect uri for the callback.html: `http://localhost:8080/#/callback`

On that route my angular app defines a Controller with the desired callback template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
        <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my root controller I already defined:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "####",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/#/callback",
});
```

Thats why the public API works for me at another controller:

```
SC.get('/resolve', {
     url: 'https://soundcloud.com/someuser'
}, function(user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

But in that same Controller the following returns 401:

```
SC.get('/me', function(me) {
    console.log(me);
});
```

Sure, because there is no dialog popping up to login!

So what did I do wrong by setting up the callback.html?

My assumptions:

1. Is it, because there is that /#/ in that URL? I already tried it with `<base href="/">` and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` but it didn't change anything.
2. Is it, because I should serve the callback.html not in my SPA environment. So more like an independent static page?
3. Is there a wrong mapping to the callback.html?
4. I am using webpack as build tool. Could there be anything wrong with that?
5. Do I have to set something else than the redirect uri at my Soundcloud App?

I hope so much that someone can help me with that!

Comment: Hey any news about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My website is angularjs+soundcloud too,
To be sure, I dont see the SC.connect function in your code, is it somewhere else?

my function in my controller:

```
this.connect= function(){

            SC.connect(function(response){

                SC.get("/me", function(response){
                    // console.log(response);
                    var data={};
                    data.token = SC.accessToken();
                    data.id = response.id;
                    $rootScope.user.sc_id=data.id;
                    $rootScope.user.sc_token=data.token;
                    soundcloud.saveToken(data);
                    soundcloud.generateAuthString();

                    //other things

        });
    });

 }
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake to forget SC.connect ;) Thank you for that!